# Efficient way to diagonalize a sparse, block tridiagonal matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, matrix, sparse-matrix

Is there an efficient way to diagonalize a block tridiagonal NxN matrix? The matrix is made up of blocks of size K with N = 2 * K * K.

I need an algorithm that scales way better than the standard O(N^3) scaling, since I am usually interested in N ca. 20.000 and K ca.  100 and need to diagonalize a lot of them. I need both the eigenvalues AND the eigenvectors, if possible to full precision.

Further information, if useful: The matrix I am considering is hermitian, the off-diagonal matrices are just the unit matrix and the matrices on the main diagonal are pentagonal. I implemented the exact form of my matrix in this minimal reproducable example (python):

```
import scipy.linalg as linalg
import numpy as np

#N is usually in this form and I want to be able to have a code that is still fast, if  I set K to a 50 or 100
K = 5
N = 2* K**2

#Creating Matrix in my form...

N_band_max = int(np.sqrt(N/2))*2

#setting bands...
Main = np.random.random(N)
Diag1 = np.random.random(N-1) + 1j*np.random.random(N-1)
Diag2 = np.ones(N-2)
Diag3 = np.ones(N-N_band_max) 

#This is for the block tridiagonal structure

for i in range(len(Diag2)):
    if(i%N_band_max == N_band_max-2 or i%N_band_max == N_band_max-1):
        Diag2[i] = 0.
        
for i in range(len(Diag1)):
    if(i%2 == 1 ):
        Diag1[i] = 0.


H = np.diag(Main) + np.diag(Diag1,1) + np.diag(Diag1.conjugate(),-1) + np.diag(Diag2,2) + np.diag(Diag2.conjugate(),-2) + np.diag(Diag3,N_band_max) + np.diag(Diag3.conjugate(),-N_band_max)

#Up to here, I just created a matrix in the desired form, for reproducibility.
#This is the part I want to be FASTER. Basically, if you find any function
#that produces the same output for the constructed matrix in less time for big K, the question is solved.
EigVals,EigVecs = linalg.eigh(H)
```

I'd be grateful for any help. I've also read this paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0217

but while it in principle provides an algorithm for my problem, I was not able to implement it efficiently (in python) and the authors did not publish their code.

(The same question from a mathematical standpoint and with a nice latex format is here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/427654/diagonalizing-a-block-tridiagonal-matrix)

Comment: I am not very conversant with matrix algebra - but could you please provide a minimal example? For a sample tri-diagonal matrix, what is the diagonalized output you want from it?

Comment: I provided a minimal example. The diagonalized output I want is equivalent to the eigenvalues of the matrix, since the desired diagonal matrix just has the eigenvalues on its diagonal. The example i provide above already calculates these eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a sample matrix (a small blocktridiagonal matrix) in the last line of the code, but the bare scipy.linalg.eigh function is not fast enough for my purposes. Did this answer your question? Thx already.

Comment: The only way improve on `eigh` is to write linked method(s) in well written `c` code.  You may test ideas in python, but the speed will be poor.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I would also be willing to code this part in c++ etc. if needed, I just have no idea, how exactly to do it or if eigh is really already as good as it gets. Because eigh scales as ~O(N^3), but I expect a solution to be realizable that has ~O(N^2) scaling, due to the matrix-sparseness.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh ?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat no, unfortunately the sparse version can not calculate all Eigenvectors and -values. Only a handful of EVs can be obtained in short time. I do however need all EVs.

Comment: The provided paper is pretty hard to read for people in this website that are mainly programmers and not mathematicians. While there are some people with a good math knowledge, the chance they also have a good knowledge in code optimization, take the time to read the paper, write the algorithm and provide a complete answer in the next few days is very very small. If you want more help, I think you need to provide a naive implementation of the method provided in the paper (removing the need to read the paper and to have advanced math skills).